# Confused about using ViewState with dynamically added usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate, webusercontrol

On my webpage I am loading multiple instances of a usercontrol, sometimes the usercontrol is laoded within itself. I need to save a bunch of properties for the round trip of a post back but i am confused on how to save those properties to ViewState and set them again to the repeater items within the usercontrol.

Can anyone help me in this situation, I have read the MSDN on Viewstate but I am not understanding it quite well for some reason

This is how I load the parent user controls (child controls are loaded the same way with the same user control)

```
Protected Sub Load_Controls(ByVal list As List(Of BSEvaluationGroup.category), ByVal gid As Integer, ByVal pid As Integer, ByVal fid As Integer)
    Dim item As BSEvaluationGroup.category
    For Each item In list
        Dim ctl As PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl.ascx"), PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl)
        ctl.categoryid = item.catid
        ctl.categoryname = item.catname
        ctl.projectid = pid
        ctl.folderid = fid
        ctl.groupid = gid
        ctl.parentid = item.parid
        ctl.clist = item.categories
        ctl.plist = item.points
        ctl.parentpage = Me
        ctl.EnableViewState = "true"
        If (Not subcon Is Nothing AndAlso Not subcon.points Is Nothing) Then
            ctl.epnts = subcon.points
        End If
        AddHandler ctl.BubbleCalculate, AddressOf Me.PostRating

        Select Case gid
            Case 1
                Me.officephld.Controls.Add(ctl)
                Dim ohrule As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("hr")
                ohrule.Style.Add("width", "100%")
                ohrule.Style.Add("background-color", "Silver")
                ohrule.Style.Add("size", "1px")
                ohrule.Style.Add("border-width", "0")
                ohrule.Style.Add("padding-top", "1px")
                ohrule.Style.Add("float", "left")
                Me.officephld.Controls.Add(ohrule)
            Case 2
                Me.sitephld.Controls.Add(ctl)
                Dim shrule As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("hr")
                shrule.Style.Add("width", "100%")
                shrule.Style.Add("background-color", "Silver")
                shrule.Style.Add("size", "1px")
                shrule.Style.Add("border-width", "0")
                shrule.Style.Add("padding-top", "1px")
                shrule.Style.Add("float", "left")
                Me.sitephld.Controls.Add(shrule)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us how you create your UserControl dynamically. Can't you add those properties as server controls(f.e. TextBox) in your UserControl. On this way these properties would be stored in ViewState automatically. Otherwise you simply have to add them manually: `ViewState("MyProperty1") = value`

Comment: I added the code to load the controls. "ctl.epnts = subcon.points" is used for the AjaxControlToolKit rating control that is loaded in the repeater.

Comment: ... and where are you calling `Load_Controls`? Remember that you have to reload them even on postback with the same ID's as before.

Comment: The load controls method is being called on Page_Init

Comment: You can write ViewState in Page_Init but you cannot read it since it's too early in page lifecycle. Page_Load would be better if you need both ways. But to be honest i've yet not understand what actually your problem is.

Comment: I will try to explain better. My problem is within my webpage, it dynamically loads awebusercontrol recursively and mostofthe time loads the webusercontrol within itself. Each webusercontrol has properties that are set for ids of various items, also there is a repeater control and within this repeater control, for each repeater item there is a visible rating control, there is a hidden control that should store the previous rating (if any). Each rating control has its AutoPostBack set to false because it is a custom rating using the gauge version,

Comment: (CONT...) if set to postback to true the rating image for the new valuedoesnt work. But my problem is I do not know how to retrieve the old value if I store it and I dont know how to store the selected value for postback so i can reset the rating current value to what was origianlly selected on postback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a control ID issue, I removed it instead of adding an ID

Answer (score 0):

Accessing view-state is simple such as `ViewState("PropertyName")`. The View State bag is specific to a control instance so you can use same property name within multiple control types and instances.

Only important thing here is that ASp.NET run-time has to match view-state bags to control instances and for that it uses ID property (which is unique within the parent naming container). So its important that you assign unique IDs to your dynamic user control instances ( and maintain same control tree hierarchy and ids on postback - essentially it means that execute the same code on postback and don't use random ids). So your code should be something like

```
...
Dim n As Integer
n = 1
For Each item In list
        Dim ctl As PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl.ascx"), PerformanceEvaluationSubcontractorControl)
        ctl.ID = "MyCtl" & n.ToString()
        ctl.categoryid = item.catid
....
```

Comment: I tried setting each user control to a unique id (ctl.ID = item.groupid & item.catid) but on post back, Viewstate has nothing within it

Comment: the following method is used for the changing of the rating control value within the repeater         Protected Sub pntrating_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs)
            Dim ctl As AjaxControlToolkit.Rating = CType(sender, AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)
            ViewState(ctl.ClientID) = ctl.ClientID
            e.CallbackResult = e.Value
        End Sub

Comment: @mattgcon, ensure that IDs are present in entire control tree heirachy i.e. user control's parent has ID and so on. Apart from that, where are you adding your user controls to the page/parent - `Load_Controls` doesn't have any such code. Regardless, ID should be assigned before adding control to the page.

Comment: The usercontrol can add another instance of the usercontrol to itself. Is there anywhere on the internet that I can show the code, a place with more room to show everything